# Voting system with Backbone.js

Tags: mongodb, backbone.js

I have a `Book` model that has the property `upVotes`. `Book` instances can be queried from the database (MongoDB), modified, and then saved. If a user upvotes a book, I update the `upVotes` count, and save the whole model back to the server.

The problem is that if someone else votes between the time the instance is loaded, and the time the instance is saved, then the two votes will be saved as just one vote. What I need is an easy way to say "increment the model by 1 server-side", instead of "increment the model by 1 client-side and hope there will be no conflict".

Comment: I just ran into exact same problem. Great question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to save the whole model to the server just to change one thing, you can (and should in this case) add an `upVote` method to your model that does an "increment upvotes" AJAX call to your server. In your model you'd have something like this:

```
upVote: function() {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/some/upvote/path',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            self.set('upVotes', data.upVotes);
        },
        // ...
    });
}
```

And then the view would have this to handle the upvote action:

```
upVote: function() {
    // Highlight the upvote button or provide some other feedback that
    // the upvote has been seen.
    this.model.upVote();
}
```

and you'd probably have a listener for change events on the model's `upVotes` property to properly increment the displayed upvote counter (if you have such a thing).

Furthermore, your `/some/upvote/path` on the server would just send an [`$inc` update](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-$inc) into MongoDB to avoid the same "two things happening at once" problem on your server. If you were using a relational database, you'd want to end up doing something like `update t set upvotes = upvotes + 1 where id = ?`.

There is no need for a "query, update, save" round trip on either the client or the server for a simple increment operation. Instead, treat the increment as a single increment operation and push that increment all the way down to your final persistent data storage layer.