# Tastypie patch override

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

My model has a counter field that increases every time a user hits a link in the front end. I'm using Backbone to send data as so

```
this.model.save({'increaseCount': true}, {'patch': true});
```

Since there is no 'increaseCount' field in the database, I'd like to get the current value of the 'counter' field and increase it by 1.

Am I on the right track? Should I use a different approach? How do I go about implementing it by writing a custom obj_update (or some other) method of the Resource?

Thanks!

Comment: Not quite a complete duplicate but the answer is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8689027/479863

Comment: @muistooshort, thanks but I wouldn't like to create a custom path for the ajax  call. I'd like to create obj_update method of a Resource and put my login in there.

Comment: Why don't you want to add another route? REST is a guideline, it isn't gospel that thou shalt obey without question. Add another route and make it easy or kludge in a bunch of machinery to make your fake `increaseCount` property work, the decision seems pretty clear to me.